# Extract Data Between Parenthesis That's Always Different Lengths

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I have run into a problem and I cannot seem to find the correct solution anywhere. I'd like to extract data from a column that is never going to be the same length but, will always be in parenthesis. I've tried different SUBSTR and LOCATE statements to no avail.

Table: **FiguresLog**

```
|UpdateDate|    |Description|
|2014-01-01|    |(10.0.600.1) Various descriptions follow|
|2014-01-02|    |(192.168.10.100) Various descriptions follow|
```

I need to be able to extract (create a new table/field) containing the IP Addresses within the parenthesis and as I stated, they will always be a different length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the whole thing using LOCATE and SUBSTR.  Because of how SUBSTR takes position and length, the math gets a little funky.  Hopefully this example makes it clear:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(text, ip_start, ip_len) AS ip_addr
FROM
(
  SELECT text,
    (LOCATE('(', text) + 1) AS ip_start,
    (LOCATE(')', text) - (LOCATE('(', text) + 1)) AS ip_len
  FROM test
) temp;
```

Notice that `(LOCATE('(', text) + 1)` gets repeated.  The `+ 1` is so we don't include the parenthesis in the substring.
The actual calculation for `ip_len` is `ip_len = end_paren_pos - ip_start` but we cannot create and select from `ip_start` in the same query.

Example in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2845e/3

Comment: **I ran the statement below and it returns all blank rows. Any idea why or where I messed up?**



SELECT 
  SUBSTR(Description, ip_start, ip_len) AS ip_addr
FROM
(
  SELECT Description,
    (LOCATE('(', Description) + 1) AS ip_start,
    (LOCATE(')', Description) - (LOCATE('(', Description) + 1)) AS ip_len
  FROM sl.figureslog
) temp;

Comment: You nested one level too deep.  Your innermost query `FROM sl.figureslog` doesn't include `Description`, yet the next level of nesting attempts to select it.  Here's an updated fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cd8c1/5

Comment: I see now. Thank you so much for the detailed help and for the fast response! It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regular expressions.  But, if there is only one parenthetical expression  in the string, this should work for you:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(description, ')', 1), '(', -1) as IpAddress
```

Comment: There's a bug in your SQL statement. The second `count` should be `-1`, not `2`.